# Is there a size limitation on the String value for "UserData" in A Launch Configuration in a CloudFormation Template?

Tags: ruby, json, aws-cloudformation, aws-sdk

I have a Cloudformation template that works fine. When I add Userdata for one of the Launch configurations in Base64 form, the CloudFormation Ruby API replies my JSON is not well formed.
This is the line:

```
        "UserData": "VERY_LONG_BASE64_ENCODED_STRING_WHICH SPANS SEVERAL LINES",
```

When I used a short one, there are no errors, So I assume my template is fine. Is this strictly a size issue or is there something more ?

Comment: How long is your data? Also JSON doesn't allow actual newlines in strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual problem:
This caused newlines inside the JSON. (Thanks Frederick Cheung for the solution)
Changed the Ruby code to remove newlines from the Base64 encoded data, all is well now. Thanks!